# Vim pascal formatting not functionning

Tags: vim, indentation, pascal, text-formatting

Vim doesn't indent at all my pascal file. When i type  `gg=G` all my code goes to the left of the screen, just erasing all of the previous indentation. 
Should I use a pascal specific indentation file ?

Before indentation by vim : 
[my file before indentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkCfm.png)

after vim indentation : [file after indentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhsfP.png)

Comment: pascal really? Well that's a language i haven't heard in a long time. Have a look here https://github.com/boeckmann/vim-freepascal

Comment: Probably because most of the Pascal users just use Lazarus, which has a great editor.

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo: It is rapidly gaining popularity again. It is the base for Object Pascal based products like Delphi, FreePascal, etc. It used to be an insider tip, but is not only a tip for insiders anymore.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis thanks, that's quite interesting, seems to live forever. Anyway there are  vim syntax files fo rdelphi, freepascal and so on.

Comment: Thanks you i will take a look at your link!